# Facebook page app linking to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a Facebook "page". In the space where the apps appear, I'd like to show an image which links to a specific page on my website.

Sounds really simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. I presume someone somewhere must have made an app that does this, but I can't track it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way currently described is against Facebook [policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

> The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an external site.

You can create a custom page tab which presents a similar page to your specific page on your website.

For more information, see the [Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)